# How to connect mic on USB sound card and bluetooth speaker with Raspberry pi3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio, pulseaudio, amazon

I am building my own Echo device following the link below
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi

Facing issue with mic and speaker set up.

I have connected my bluetooth speaker with raspberry pi 3 and its functioning correctly. 
How can now connect mic (with usb sound card) to raspberry pi 3?

Following are the pulse audio settings on my raspberry pi 3

[image: pairing JBL GO]

[image: Pulse Audio Settings and Config]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I used this [PnP USB microphone](https://www.amazon.com/VAlinks-Microphone-Recording-Compatible-Raspberry/dp/B014MASID4) which worked after I plugged it in and rebooted. I don't think a reboot was warranted, but I still did it anyway. I did not have to change any settings or do anything specific.

Comment: I too have ordered one.. waiting for delivery!

Comment: It works perfectly. I first ordered the same mini USB microphone that was referenced in the Github page, but that ships from China and regular shipping takes too long. That's why I went with this one. It is fun using a DIY Alexa device!